# Find the maximum number of pieces a rod can be cut

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Here is the complete problem statement:

Given a rope of length n, you need to find the maximum number of pieces 
you can make such that the length of every piece is in set {a, b, c} for 
the given three values a, b, c

I know that the optimal solution can be achieved through Dynamic Programming, however, I have not learned that topic yet and I need to solve this problem recursively. With recursion, the main thing is to identify a subproblem and that's what I'm mainly having difficulty with doing. Can anyone give me an intuitive way to think of this problem? Sort of like a higher level description of the recursion if that makes sense. Is there an easier problem similar to this that I can try first that would help me solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's already quite simple, with recursion we can just check all posibilities, in one step we can either cut away a piece of length `a`, `b`, or `c` so from problem of size `n` we get sup-problem of smaller size `n-x`

Of course we need a base case, so when `n=0` we have succeeded so we can return `0`, in case of `n < 0` we have failed so we can return some negative infinity constant

Sample pseudo-code:

```
int solve(int n){
    if(n < 0) return -123456789; //-Infinity
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    return 1 + max(solve(n-a), solve(n-b), solve(n-c));
}
```

going to dynamic programming is as simple as setting up memo lookup table

```
int solve(int n){
    if(n < 0) return -123456789; //-Infinity
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    if(n in memo)return memo[n]
    return memo[n] = 1 + max(solve(n-a), solve(n-b), solve(n-c));
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why we need to add 1 to the final result?

Comment: we cut away a piece of size `a / b / c` so that took 1 step, other steps will be handled by recrusion so we recurse

Comment: Just one more thing, should the mins in your solution be maxs?

Comment: oh yeah misread the question that we need minimum amount of cuts somehow, updated the answer

Comment: test with n = 9, a=2, b=2, c=2. @Photon

Answer (score 2):

```
int maxcut(int n, int a,int b,int c)
{

    if(n==0) return 0;

    if(n<0) return 1;

    int result = max( maxcut(n-a,a,b,c), maxcut(n-b,a,b,c), maxcur(n-c,a,b,c));

    if(res == -1) return -1;

    return(result+1)

 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The way we should tackle the recursion problem is:

1. Finding the recursion case (Finding the subproblems)
2. Finding the base case (The last subproblem case we cannot break in subproblems)

Specific to this problem :

1. Recursion case: Cutting rope we all the possible values till we cannot break it further smaller subproblem.
2. Base case: a. It can be completely cut. (valid try)
   b.It can't be completely cut. (invalid try)

int maxcut(int n, int a,int b,int c)
{

```
if(n==0) return 0; //base case a.

if(n<0) return -1; //base case b.

int result = max( maxcut(n-a,a,b,c), maxcut(n-b,a,b,c), maxcur(n-c,a,b,c)); //subproblems for all the cases

if(res == -1) return -1; // boundry coundtion

return(result+1); //to count the valid conditions and return to parent
```

}

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete code for your problem

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int max(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            if (a > c)
            {
    
                return a;
            }
        
        else
        {
            return c;
        }
        }
    
    else
    {
        if (b > c)
        {
    
            return b;
        }
    
        else
        {
            return c;
        }
    }
    
    }
    
    int maxpiece(int l, int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int r;
        if (l == 0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (l<0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        
    
        r = max(maxpiece(l-a, a, b, c), maxpiece(l-b, a, b, c), maxpiece(l-c, a, b, c));
    
        if (r == -1)
            return -1;
    
        return r + 1;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int lenth;
        cout << "enter rope lenth ";
        cin >> lenth;
        int p1, p2, p3;
        cout << endl
             << "enter the only three parameters in which rope can be cut ";
        cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3;
        cout << endl
             <<"ans = "<< maxpiece(lenth, p1, p2, p3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int cutRope(int n, int a, int b, int c){
// Base cases
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    if(n < 0) return -1;

    int res = max(max(cutRope(n - a, a, b, c), cutRope(n - b, a, b, c)), cutRope(n - c, a, b, c));

    if(res == -1) return -1;
    return res + 1;
}

int main() {
    cout << cutRope(23, 11, 9, 12) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most naive method using recursion is to cut rope by each length at repeat until

1. we have completely cut the rope
2. or there is not valid cut, that is rope length becomes -ve.

Extreme elaborative solution

1. Store result of each branch into a separate variable

   res1 = maxCuts(n-a, a, b, c);

   res2 = maxCuts(n-b, a, b, c);

   res3 = maxCuts(n-c, a, b, c);
2. Compare these results for each root

result = MaxOf(res1, res2, res3)

3. if invalid cut result, simply return -1
4. else add one to result and return for this root.

   int maxCuts(int n, int a, int b, int c)
   {
   if(n == 0)
   return 0;
   if(n < 0)
   return -1;

   ```
            int res1 = maxCuts(n-a, a, b, c);
            int res2 = maxCuts(n-b, a, b, c);
            int res3 = maxCuts(n-c, a, b, c);

            int res = Math.max(res1, Math.max(res2, res3));

            if(res == -1)
                return -1;

            return res + 1; 
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With **recursion** the worst time complexity is `O(3^n)` when a, b and c are of length 1. I have drawn the recursion tree to help to understand rope cutting problem in an easier way.

[image]

In this recursion tree we can get the idea of the base condition using the leaf nodes i.e 0 and -1. Zero means no more cutting of the pieces and -1 means the solution is negative.

**Using this recursion tree**, here is the code snippet

```
 def rope_cutting(n, a, b, c):
     # base condition
     if n == 0:
         return 0
     if n <= -1:
         return -1
     res = max(rope_cutting(n - a, a, b, c),
              rope_cutting(n - b, a, b, c),
              rope_cutting(n - c, a, b, c),
              )
     if res == -1:
         return -1

     return res + 1


 n = 5
 a = 2
 b = 5
 c = 1

 output = rope_cutting(
                      n=n,
                      a=a,
                      b=b,
                      c=c
                      )
 print(output)
```

There is a condition that if **res = -1**, then return -1 because there can be a problem where no combination of a, b and c will make total length n like if n is odd and a, b and c are even then result would be -1.

The solution can be achieved using time complexity `theta(n)` using dynamic programming approach. Below is the pseudo code for that.
**Step 1:** Create the array of size n + 1, where n is the total length of rope.
**Step 2:** Initialize this array with -1.
**Step 3:** Equate the first value of the array equals to 0.
**Step 4:** Run for loop from (1, n + 1) and have the below conditions

```
Condition 1: if i >= a, then dp[i] = dp[i - a]  
Conditon 2: if i >= b, then dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[i - b])  
Condition 3: if i >= c, then dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[i - c])  
Now after putting the value if dp[i] != -1, then dp[i] += 1
```

**Step 5:** Return dp[n]

**Code is as below**

```
def rope_cut_dp(n, a, b, c):

    dp = [-1 for i in range(n + 1)]
    dp[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if i >= a:
            dp[i] = dp[i - a]
        if i >= b:
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[i - b])
        if i >= c:
            dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[i - c])
        if dp[i] != -1:
            dp[i] += 1

    return dp[n]
```