# Print the ropes length left after it is cut from the set

Tags: recursion

There is this question which cut the ropes using length from the sets (a,b,c) and return the maximum number of ropes that can be cut from the larger rope .I want a function to print the length which is cut. for example if n=5 and the set is (2,1,3). I want to print all the ways to cut the rope like (2,3) ,(1,2,2) etc.I would know how do you choose using recursion the path to 1 leaf .Like here we need to print the maximize the number of ropes that are cut.like (1,1,1,1,1).

print the rope

```
int func(n){
    if(n==0)return 0;
    if(n<0)return -1;
    return 1+max(func(n-a),func(n-b),func(n-c);
}
```

It is this question [Find the maximum number of pieces a rod can be cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250075/find-the-maximum-number-of-pieces-a-rod-can-be-cut) but the added part is to print the segments also.

Comment: If you have the solution for cutting the rope (without the logic to print each segment), put that in the question.

Comment: I have added the code to print the maximum number of pieces

Comment: What is `a`, `b`, and `c` here?

Comment: a,b,c are the only set of lengths that the rope is allowed to be cut in.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? How are you calling func(n)? Where do you collect the outputs?

Comment: That's the question i am confused on how to collect the outputs from the recursion tree. Someone asked me to write the code for printing the maximum number of rope cuts.So I did in the question.

Comment: Why " n=5 and the set is (2,1,3)"? Isn't that equals to 6? (2+1+3)

Comment: Given a rope of length n, you need to find the maximum number of pieces
you can make such that the length of every piece is in set {a, b, c} for
the given three values a, b, c
This is the question that is there but instead of just returning the value of maximum pieces that can be cut ,I want to print the values of the pieces that gives the maximum cut.